# Writing to a file in my iOS app

Tags: ios, file-io

I have an app that downloads files that need to be edited and submitted back to the server through the app.  These files could be anything, but are most likely to be .docs.  I want to be able to open and edit these files in another app on the device, such as a .doc editor.

I've been able to get this functionality to work in similar Android and Chrome apps, but I'm very new to iOS so I'm not sure what my options are.

Is there a way to give permission for another app to edit a file that is in my app's sandbox?  If not, is there a way to get the file back for submittal (like finding it through a file explorer launched through my app - similar to an 'Open..." file explorer dialog used in Windows/Mac OS/Chrome)?  Am I going to have to create a way for the editor app to share the edited file back to my app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To manage the file and the paths take a look at the documentation for NSFileManager:

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I usually write using NSFileHandle for reading and writing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just wondering why you choose `NSFileHandle` over the `NSFileManager` methods.

Comment: They serve different purposes. 
NSFileManager allows you to manage the paths and check if a file exits, you can create the file but the writing and reading is done thorough NSFileHandle.

They do different things one manage paths and file status the other one manages edition, read

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 will provide methods to allow apps to co-operate with "extensions".

See "Creating Extensions for iOS and OS X, Part 1 & 2` in the WWDC14 videos.
Also see the Apple "App Extension Programming Guide".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the file to a 3rd party app for editing and then sending the file back from the 3rd app to my app.